# CloudRun Express App - Report custom message to GCP Error Reporting on SyntaxError

Tags: node.js, express

I got express app written in NodeJS.
When users send a request with malformed Json (for instance comma is missing)
I would like to return 400 with custom message to the user and to report this message to the Error Reporting.
My code goes like that:

```
app.use(function (error, req, res, next) {
  console.log(error);
  if (error instanceof SyntaxError) {
    let response = {
      Message: 2,
      Errors: [{ Code: VALIDATION_ERR_CODE, Description: INVALID_MESSAGE_FORMAT }],
      TimeStamp: moment.utc(new Date()).format(DATE_TIME_FORMAT)
    };
    
    
    return res.status(400).send(response);
  }
  else
  next(); 
});
```

The user got the custom message as desired:

```
{
    "Message": 2,
    "Errors": [
        {
            "Code": 2100000000,
            "Description": "Invalid message format"
        }
    ],
    "TimeStamp": "20210322142420102"
}
```

But Error Reporting got the real problem:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected string in JSON at position 74
JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

How do I custom the error that sends to the Error Reporting and prevent from the real syntax error exception message to appear?

I would like to see on Error Reporting the message "Invalid message format" instead of "SyntaxError: Unexpected string in JSON at position 74"

Comment: What check and raise the error? The logs should come from the JSON parser.

Comment: Can you share a screenchot of your logs?

Answer (score 0):

You could instead of:

```
console.log(error);
```

write this inside:

```
if (error instanceof SyntaxError) {
  ...
  console.log("Invalid message format")
  ...
}
```